# Secondary loop cuts off at 10 posts?

Tags: loop, templates, tags, categories

I have a loop to get a tag name from the URL slug, and then show all the posts, grouped by category, that matched that tag. It works, but I recently noticed it only shows 10 posts despite my setting (I thought) posts_per_page to -1.

I want to show **all** the posts that match the tag, grouped by category.  Here's the code:

```
<?php
// get all the categories from the database
$cats = get_categories();

$slug = the_slug();

// loop through the categories
foreach ($cats as $cat) {
    // setup the category ID
    $cat_id= $cat->term_id;

    // create a custom wordpress query
    query_posts("cat=$cat_id&tag=$slug&post_per_page=-1&orderby=title&order=ASC");

    // start the wordpress loop!
    if (have_posts()) :

    // Make a header for the category
    echo '<h2 class="group-title">'.$cat->name.'</h2>';

    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php // create our link now that the post is setup ?>
        <div class="listing">
         <div class="listing-name"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php //include('custom-fields.php'); ?>
        </div>

        <?php //echo '<hr/>'; ?>

    <?php endwhile; endif; // done our wordpress loop. Will start again for each category     ?>
<?php } // done the foreach statement ?>
```

Comment: `post_per_page` should be `posts_per_page`, but [never use `query_posts`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)

Comment: @Milo +15 for that comment. I think sometimes users should search WPSE more often. Some answers are even better than that found elsewhere, sometimes even the codex